# Should I convert my jquery scripts to objects or let it be?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I have been recently reproducing the new twitter ui(sliding panes) and I have built quite a similar(if not slightly better) functionality for it. I don't have some problems with it recently until a couple of bugs surfaced when I tried to refactor. That said, I am at a crossroads as to deciding if I should refactor my code and use OOP.

For a little background as to what I did, I have a list of items which have the expandable class. Inside them, i have a div called ".inner" in which I put the data for the right side there. I then have a $('.expandable') click function that animates the right pane and clones all the contents of the .inner div and puts it in the right pane.

When the page loads, the I create a number of right side panes with the class ".pane" which is hidden under the left side pane. I could go on with my implementation as needed but what I was thinking was to convert each of these huge click functions etc and just create say a Pane object which has all the methods for animating, hiding, itself etc.

Problem with this is I am not sure if it is a good idea, especially if there are a lot of panes. Will turning my panes into objects increase or decrease load time/functionality? Is a click event tied to a class( $('.expandable').click() ) faster than if expandable was a method of a Pane object? What about if there were 30 Panes/expandable things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on what you want to do you can either just use the selector engine and objects or what I do is express my JQuery plugins as objects with state but visible to the 'outside' world as ordinary plugins.

I also put utility features such as client caching, parsers etc into objects as these aren't about browser interaction and more about a re-usable inner api.

But it really boils down to how you want to code. The JQuery plugin library and API are quite rich but if you're finding you need a little more then objects are the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about, but when I used to do a script in javascript, I ever use jQuery because is this who organise the memory and the objects. I also have to say that in more of my cases (when I use jQuery to load more than 1000 points on a map) the Firefox had a good response. The problem was in Internet Explorer.

I recommend to you, all as you can, use OOP in javascript. If it's posible, with jQuery (has a great community to help). Also, you have to see the IE hacks to improve the jQuery in this 'navigator'.

You could check also this webpage: http://plugins.jquery.com/ . There, you can find a lot of pluguins for do the most important and common functionality with jQuery.